# Java run Python script Issue

Tags: java, python, cmd, process, runtime.exec

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\xxxxxxx\\python.exe", "C:\\xxxxxxxxxx\\1.py");
pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();
```

I am trying to run Python script from my Java program. The problem is, java run doesn't give me any result. In Python script, there is an OCR operation and I am writing a txt file.

CMD - Manually - It runs OK 
Python IDLE - Manually - It runs OK 
.bat doesn't work. with administrative rights doesn't work. 
Java run doesn't work.

I need help, I need to run the script from java program.

Comment: What error you are getting in .bat and in java? Did you try `p.start()`? Starting process stored in `p`

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari the error is about the python code. The problem is why I am getting error when I run the python script from Java, With the python idle, there is no problem

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and (continue to) use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The problem is;

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\xxxxxxx\\python.exe", "C:\\xxxxxxxxxx\\1.py");
pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();
```

**When you run this code, python script will process operations in that directory, I mean in your Java class' directory. No matter where py file is.**

In my case, there were 'image.save("x.png")' lines in the python script. I hoped that images will be saved in the directory where the py file is. But it is not like that.